# Kotlin: Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I'm new to Kotlin,  for the piece of the below code:

```
fun a(stcd: String) {
        val res = mutableSetOf<String>()
        val aaa = mutableListOf<Map<String, Set<String>>>()
        aaa.stream().filter { x: Map<String, Set<String>> -> x.isNotEmpty() }
            .filter { x: Map<String, Set<String>> ->
                x.values.contains(stcd) // throws error
            }.forEach { x: Map<String, Set<String>> ->
                x.forEach { (k: String, v: Set<String>?) ->
                    res.add(k)
                }
            }
    }
```

Could anyone point out why `contains` throws error:`Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly.`?

Comment: You start with _aaa_ which is an empty list, you filter it – for no purpose as the list is empty anyway – and then assign the items – and there are none – to _res_, which you do not use in nor return from the function. So what is the purpose of this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `x.values` is not a `Set<String>`, as you probably think it is. In fact, it's a`Collection<Set<String>>` as per the definition of `values`. So, such a collection can't contain a `String` type.